# Field extension of odd degree whose Galois group is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $n\geq 1$ be an odd integer. Show there exists a field extension $L$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ such that $|\mathrm{Gal}(L/\Bbb{Q})|= 1$.

Comment: In general, the order of the Galois group equals the degree of the Galois extension.

Comment: @Watson In general this is not true. For example, $\mathrm{Gal} (\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) / \Bbb{Q})$ is trivial.

Comment: @Crostul : your extension is not normal, so it is not Galois. I'm just saying that the extension $L$ can't be Galois over $\Bbb Q$ if it has trivial Galois group and has degree $>1$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the following theorem:

> Let $F/K$ be a finite separable extension of degree $n$. Then $L/K$ is normal if and only if the group of $K$-automorphisms of $L$ has $n$ elements.

In particular, this means that your extension cannot be normal (except for the trivial case $n =1$). Hence, I will use the notation $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ for non-normal extensions, denoting the group of $K$-automorphisms of $L$.

For all odd $n \ge 3$, the extension $L= \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})$ does the job. This is because any $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphism of $L$ must fix $\Bbb{Q}$ (by definition), and must fix $\sqrt[n]{2}$ (it's the unique root of $X^n-2$ belonging to $L$); in particular, identity is the unique $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphism of $L$.

For $n=2$ this is impossible, since any quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ is normal, and its Galois group has two elements.

Comment: I've usually only seen the symbol Gal used for normal extensions..

Comment: @Jake Yes, usually this is used only for normal extensions. But since in the contest of normal extensions this question does not make sense, I thought that maybe the symbol $\mathrm{Gal}$ could have this "generalized meaning". Actually one can define the Galois group of any extension (it's the group of automorphisms fixing the base field).

Comment: @Crostu did you mean its order is 1 due to the unique Q-automorphism of L(identity)?

Comment: @A.Get Yes, of course.

Answer (score -1):

The answer of Crostul is right only for odd $n$. For an even $n$ it doesn't work, because all the roots are $ \sqrt[n]{2}e^{2 \pi i k/n}$ for $k$ from $0$ to $ n-1.$
So if n is even, in the exponent we get $\frac{ 2 \pi i K}{n}= \frac{ \pi i k}{n/2}$ for $K=0,...,n-1$.
At this moment  for $K_1 = 0,... n/2-1$ and $K_2= n/2 ,...,n$  we realize that $e^{\frac{\pi i k_1}{n/2}}=-e^{\frac{\pi i k_2}{n/2}}$ due to the fact that $e^{\frac{n/2 \pi i}{n/2}}=e^{\pi i}=-1$

Hence $ \sqrt[n]{2}, -\sqrt[n]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})$
and there is no longer a unique root in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})$

Comment: The question specifically asks for $n$ odd; so of course the answer need only work for odd $n$. Your critique then is misplaced.